# Using spring loaded with spring boot and maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-loaded

I'm creating an extremely simple Spring example as described here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and I'm running it with `mvn spring-boot:run`. Now I want to add Spring Loaded plugin in there so that I as soon as I compile a java file, it should be compiled and reloaded. Hewever,

- I don't want to use Gradle
- I don't want to use Eclipse or Idea

Is there a simple way to set up Spring Loaded in Maven so that I can use it from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add the springloaded jar as a dependency in the plugin configuration, e.g. [as in the JPA sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/f97251b9cf80aa5cda21340d6cbcd28852db5c14/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/pom.xml#L46).
Here's a link to the plugin docs: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#agent

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up reverting to Grails. Spring misses on too many basic things.